# How can I reverse colors of a two-colors photo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I've this image:

[image]

As you see, there are only two colors used in the image above. All I'm trying to do is replacing all brown colors with white and vice versa.

Is doing that possible via Photoshop CC ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the image in Photoshop.

Create a new layer above the image layer.

Go to Select - Color Range - A dialog box will open. Then select the brown color in the image.

A selection will appear.
Set the foreground color to white and then press Alt+Delete on the new layer created above the image layer. This will fill the selection with white color.

Deselect the selection.

Now create a new layer between the the original image and the image with white fill.
Select the brown color with eyedropper tool and fill the background with brown color.

[image]